# Windows Phone 8 apps backward compatiability

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Here is a little question bothering me around, everybody is asking about will wp7 apps run on wp8? but my question is vice-versa. Apps built using sdk8 for wp8 will run on all previous windows phone mobiles especially on wp7.

Comment: No you can't run a WP8 app on WP7

Comment: is it obvious or there is way to make an app which can run on both without black bars on Lumia 920 and/or some else wp8 mobile.

Comment: Create a WP7 solution for the WP7 and create another WP8 solution for WP8 device (and link your files in the WP8 solution) http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application

Answer (score 1):

No, SDK8 uses some Windows phone 8 specific APIs, so Windows phone 7, 7.5, 7.8 users won't be able to download you app.

Comment: you mean we have to make two different apps if we want our app to run on wp7 and wp8?

Comment: No, If you want your app to run on both, just create a WP7 app. But you won't be able to use WP8 new features in your app.